# Accessibility issue with radio buttons /check boxes

Tags: accessibility

In our aplication , we are using Trinidad JSF for UI.
When user logged into the application, a page is displayed with Table of records. Radio button is displayed for each record to select a record.
When user tabs into a group of radio buttons, default dotted line appears around the radio button. And also, when User navigates within the group of radio buttons using up and down arrow key, default dotted line still remain on the selected radio button. This scenario is fine

Now, user logged into the application, a page is displayed with Table of records and user selected a radio button with the mouse button. User observed that  default dotted line does not appear around the radio button. It means that, focus is not active on the radio button.

why the dotted line not appearing on the radio button when selected with mouse button?

Browser :  IE 8.

Please write your valuable comments.

Rendered html forms like the below

```
<table>  
<tr>  
<td class="x7f xbd">  
<input name="cardholderList:selected" id="cardholderList:0" title="Select" type="radio" value="0">  
</td>  
...  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td class="x7f xbd">  
<input name="cardholderList:selected" id="cardholderList:1" title="Select" type="radio" value="1">  
</td>  
...  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td class="x7f xbd">  
<input name="cardholderList:selected" id="cardholderList:2" title="Select" type="radio" value="2">  
</td>  
...  
</tr>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If mouse clicks won't enable the outline, it's necessary to style them yourself.

```
a:active{outline:none;} 
a:focus {outline: 2px solid green;}
```